# Columns missing while creating consolidated parquet file from multiple csv files on ADF copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

we have multiple csv files generated on the source folder on ADLS Gen2,
we need to merge these to a consolidated parquet file.

Few of the columns in some of the csv's are missing.

In the copy activity, we have mentioned below properties:

1. Source:

- File Path Type: Wildcard file path
- wildcardpath: path with *.csv

2. Sink: path to consolidated parquet file
3. Mapping: we are generating schema mapping from Stored procedure passing on the all columns that are needed on parquet files.

How these missing columns can be added to the parquet in case they are not present on CSVs

Comment: why not use a dataflow? Create the missing additional columns with the values that you need and use that further?

Comment: can you please share sample in put output?

Answer (score 0):

> How these missing columns can be added to the parquet in case they are not present on CSVs

***Note: when you select Wildcard path in copy activity it takes schema of first file in alphabetical order***

To add the columns from all the files in a consolidated Parquet file you can use data flow to take all columns from all files and give proper value to the columns which are not present in all files.

- Add your source as a file and add wildcard path as per your requirement.
  [image]
- Then go to projection and import the projection it will consolidate all the columns from all the files.
  [image]

**Data preview for the same:**

[image]